# observableArray not updating with full array passed

Tags: knockout.js

I have a populated observableArray and later I need to replace the array inside of it with its correspondent UI update. It's not updating anything.

JS

```
showFirst: ko.observable(true);
orders: ko.observableArray();
orders(firstArray);

function changeArray(){orders(secondArray); showFirst(false);}
```

HTML

```
<!-- ko if: showFirst() -->
<!-- ko foreach: orders() -->
    <p data-bind="text: property1"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: showFirst() -->
<!-- ko foreach: orders() -->
    <p data-bind="text: property2"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

Even I can check with the ko extension that orders has been updated, but it keeps trying to check the property1.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
showFirst: ko.observable(true);
orders: ko.observableArray();
orders(firstArray);

function changeArray(){orders(secondArray); showFirst(false);}

<!-- ko foreach: orders() -->
    <p data-bind="text: showFirst() ? property1 : property2"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The idea is to use the ternary operator in your binding.

Comment: I have updated the question in order to reflect that hasChanged is actually not a result of the change but a flag that indicates what portion of html should be shown.

Comment: It would help if it only were a sing p tag, but I have simplified the issue. I have more or less 50 data-binds and they are different for each array. The problem is that the observableArray is not being updated in the html, not at all.

Comment: Are `firstArray` and `secondArray` observable arrays?

Comment: No they aren't.

Comment: Have you tried: `function changeArray(){orders.removeAll(); orders(secondArray); showFirst(false);}`?

Comment: or `function changeArray(){orders(secondArray); orders.valueHasMutated(); showFirst(false);}`

Answer (score 0):

*[Should be a comment, but then I couldn't share this code.]*

I can't repro this. Take a look at what's going on below and see if it helps.

```js
var model={
  showFirst: ko.observable(true),
  orders: ko.observableArray([
    {property1:"p1",property2:"p2"},
    {property1:"p11",property2:"p22"}]),
  triggeredByAClick:function(){
    this.orders([
      {property1:"pp1",property2:"pp2"},
      {property1:"pp11",property2:"pp22"}]); 
    this.showFirst(false);
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<!-- ko if: showFirst() -->
<!-- ko foreach: orders() -->
    <p data-bind="text: property1"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko ifnot: showFirst() -->
<!-- ko foreach: orders() -->
    <p data-bind="text: property2"></p>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
<button data-bind="click:triggeredByAClick">click</button>
```